# Xcode, go to an independent view controller using a button or is a tab bar required?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm confused about independent view controllers.  I need an independent view so that I can control the rotations separate from my other view (View A) and parent view (Splashview).  Can this be done by using a button on View A or does there have to be a tab bar.  Right now I just have a subclass of a UIViewController and I can't control the rotation separately from the other views.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by rotating. Do you mean pusing/flipping other controllers into the main view? usually you navigate with one view controller + buttons for each screen, or you navigate using tabs. You can also embed uiviewcontrollers, but that complicate things. Your choice.

Comment: Please add some code or a sketch of the hierarchy, it's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @Jano I'm having trouble with the shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation method.  When I try to return YES on a subview (View B), the subview will not rotate because only portrait is passed on the parentview.  Is there a way to make View B independent of all other views so when I return YES it will rotate?

Comment: With one view controller, returning YES is all you need to rotate all views. For special cases, refer to [Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html). AFAIK you can't rotate just part of the interface until you do it manually with core graphics (which is quite possible).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate only one view of your ViewController but not all of it, you have two possibilities:

- Manage the rotation yourself, by observing the device rotation notifications and change your view's `transform` property to the appropriate `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`
- Maybe you can use the "Container View Controller" pattern to have your main controller embed a child view controller which will only manage your view of interest, and which allows rotation (not tested).

See the View Controller Programming Guide in Apple's doc for more details.